# Logstash - Issue parsing json_lines format

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, jsonlines

Probably a n00b issue trying to get the json_lines codec to read data from a file.

Here's what my config file looks like

```
input {
  file {
    path => ['C:/dev/logstash-5.1.2/data/sample.log']
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => 'C:/dev/logstash-5.1.2/data/.sincedb'
    codec => "json_lines"
  }
}
output {  
  file {
    path => ['C:/dev/logstash-5.1.2/data/sample-output.log']
    flush_interval => 0
  }
}
```

Here's what my super simple input file looks like

```
{"id":1,"name":"A green door","price":12.50,"tags":["home","green"]}
{"id":2,"name":"A red door","price":12.50,"tags":["home","red"]}
```

When I switch the codec to `plain` the file gets read and output gets written as expected. But no matter what I do I'm unable to get the `json_lines` codec to read and write this data.

I am pretty new to logstash, so this might just be something simple that I'm just not able to wrap my head around. Any help would be most appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [json_lines documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/plugins-codecs-json_lines.html) it has this warning:

> NOTE: Do not use this codec if your source input is line-oriented JSON, for example, redis or file inputs. Rather, use the json codec. More info: This codec is expecting to receive a stream (string) of newline terminated lines. The file input will produce a line string without a newline. Therefore this codec cannot work with line oriented inputs.

Use the [json codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/plugins-codecs-json.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by the "Reads newline-delimited JSON" description on the codecs page of the user guide..